# なぜViewModelはrotateによるAcitivityの再生成を超えてデータを保持できるのか

Tags: android

> The ViewModel class is designed to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way. The ViewModel class allows data to survive configuration changes such as screen rotations.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel より

とあります。
ViewModelを利用する動機の一つとして、rotateで起こるActivity再生成を超えてModelを保持できることがあるそうです。
私はこれがどのようにもたらされるのか、そして「であるならばViewModelのライフサイクルはどれくらい長いのか」を調べました。

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider
- https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider#ViewModelProvider(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner)
- https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelStoreOwner

このあたりのドキュメントを参考にしたところ、

- Activityは直接ViewModelを保持しているわけではなく、ViewModelProvierによってもたらされる
- ViewModelProviderは指定されたViewModelStoreOwnerを用いてViewModelをStoreする
- ViewModelStoreOwnerをImplementsしているのは結局Activityである

ということがわかりました。
であるならば、つまるところ、Activityが直接ViewModelを保持しているのとかわりはなく、ライフサイクルの面では何の意味もないアーキテクチャに思えます。

表題の質問に戻りますが、Activityの再生成を超えてデータを保持できる理由もわかりません。
なぜなのでしょうか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決したので書きます。

rotateではActivityのdestroyとcreateを呼びはするが、Activityインスタンス自体は破棄しないからです。
つまりそもそもActivityがフィールドとして保持している値はrotateを超えて破棄されません。(onCreateで値をフォーマットしてしまわない限り！)
そのActivityをViewModelStoreOwnerとして実行されるViewModelProviderも同様です。

もし仮にrotateがActivityのインスタンスを破棄"することもある"のであれば、この枠組で取り上げているViewModelも同様に破棄されます。(そのためにsavedStateという機能があります)

---

このことは、そもそもActivityにデータ保持させるために、onCreateではなく、constructorで初期化をすれば、同様の効果を得られることを示していると思います。